# Do Muslims hold the biography (Sira) of Prophet Muhammad with the same status as the Quran and Hadith?

Tags: quran, hadith, prophet-muhammad

Does the biography ([Sira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prophetic_biography)) of the Prophet Muhammad PBUH have the same status as both the Quran and Hadith?

Comment: It would be nice if you elaborated your post and clarified what you exactly mean? As there's nothing in Islam that has the same status of the Qur'an. The hadith or sunnah follows and to some extent Sira has a similar way of transmission of both of them, but most earlier historians have an ambivalent reputation. (See also [What are the complete writings of Islam, Qur'an, Hadith, Sunnah, Tafsir ...](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35384/what-are-the-complete-writings-of-islam-quran-hadith-ahadith-sunnah-tafsir)